# Excel Template Spreadsheet For Class Design / UML?

Tags: excel, class-design

I am looking for a template `Excel` spreadsheet to use when designing classes (prior to writing any code).

Basically, I'd like to have a spreadsheet where I could see the class name, its properties (member variables, public/private methods, what they do etc), and any other relevant info.

Can you recommend on any such template for `Excel`, or for other programs?

Comment: Did you consider using a grapical UML design tool?

Comment: No, I did not. Any recommendations?

Comment: There is a bunch of eclipse based solutions. Most of them to buy, only some usefull free editions. A reasonably good open source solution is [link](http://argouml.tigris.org/)

Comment: @cmmi: thank you. Do you know if it works with `Eclipse` / `PyDev`?